# Learning Criteria instead of hql, how to query using criteria manytomany with List of objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, hql

How do I do a query when I pass an integer, as an authorId, to find the books associated with that author? I tried one below gives me a 'not an association id'. What's the proper way of doing this?

Also, this many-to-many created a third table based on the annotations on  authors attribute from books.

Entity

```
@Entity
class Book{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer  id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @Column(name="Authors")
  @JoinTable(name = "author_book", joinColumns =
    { @JoinColumn(name = "authors_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "books_id") })
  private List<Author> authors;

    //getters-setters
}

@Entity
class Author{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Book> books;

  //getters-setters
}
```

Function doing the desired behavior

```
public List<Book> getBooksByAuthorId(int authorId) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Book.class, "book");
        cr.createAlias("book.authors", "authors");
        cr.createAlias("authors.id", "authid");
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq()) //edited after  initial post this line should be removed

        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("auth.id", authorId));
        List<Book> results = cr.list();
        session.close();
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you are trying to achieve in your query?
Many-To-Many relationship should be mapped through intermediate table, so the behavior you are getting is correct.

Comment: If I pass an argument in this case, int(authorid), or even better a string, I want to return a list of books associated with that author. So I can print those list of books.

Comment: please see answer below

Comment: sorry for late reply. the error is in "book.authors". . should just be authors

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

I can suggest JPA Criteria API (differs with Hibernate Criteria API)
Hibernate Criteria API is considered as deprecated now.

To obtain list of books, associated with author by supplying author id:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
    Root book = cq.from(Book.class);
    // // declaring parameter 'authorId'
    cq.where(cb.equal(book.get("id"), cb.parameter(Integer.class, "authorId"));
    Query query = em.createQuery(cq);
      // supplying parameter 'authorId' to query
    query.setParameter("authorId", id);
    List<Author> authors = query.getResultList();
```